# 'AST not available' exception while filtering DataSet

Tags: groovy, groovy-sql

I have following groovy program -

```
def people = sql.dataSet('players')
def d = people.findAll { true }
print d.rows()
```

I get an exception at the print statement.

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: DataSet unable to evaluate expression. AST not available for closure: in.kshitiz.pgnimport.dao.PlayerDao$_get_closure1. Is the source code on the classpath?
    at groovy.sql.DataSet.visit(DataSet.java:300)
    at groovy.sql.DataSet.getSqlWhereVisitor(DataSet.java:283)
    at groovy.sql.DataSet.getSqlWhere(DataSet.java:230)
    at groovy.sql.DataSet.getSql(DataSet.java:257)
    at groovy.sql.DataSet.rows(DataSet.java:332)
    at groovy.sql.DataSet$rows.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at in.kshitiz.pgnimport.dao.PlayerDao.get(PlayerDao.groovy:13)
    at in.kshitiz.pgnimport.dao.PlayerDao$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at in.kshitiz.pgnimport.dao.PlayerDaoTest.testGet(PlayerDaoTest.groovy:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The exception is not very helpful. What does it mean?

Comment: Shouldn't `people.findAll { true }` have some some conditional statement in closure?  like `people.findAll{ it.age > 18}` ?

Comment: @kunal In the end doesn't `it.age > 18` evaluate to a boolean?

Comment: http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Problem-filtering-DataSet-td371883.html

Comment: @tim_yates That works. Would you like to add that as an answer?

Comment: @KshitizSharma Yes, you are right, I was just guessing something which was probably in wrong direction :)

Comment: @kunal Debugging is mostly guesswork. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add your groovy DAO source to the classpath to fix the problem.

In [this](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Problem-filtering-DataSet-td371883.html) mailing list, Guillaume Laforge says:

> There's a twist in the usage of the Sql class.
>
> It needs your Groovy class source code available -- like when running groovy myScript.groovy.
>
> So for instance, when a class is pre-compiled, the "class node" won't be available anymore, as it's not stored in the bytecode.
>
> That may be the issue you're facing here.
>
> The class node is needed for the `findall {}` part, where we're visiting the AST for creating an adhoc query.

From [Groovy in Action](http://www.manning.com/koenig/) (Chapter 10, page 343, para 4) -

> DataSet implementation fetches Groovy’s internal representation of
>   the closure’s code. This internal representation is called the
>   Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and was generated by the Groovy parser.
>   By walking over the AST (with a Visitor pattern), the DataSet
>   implementation emits the SQL equivalent of each AST node.

Comment: Any chance you know how to make Eclipse automatically copy `java` files to `target`?